# HTML5 phone number validation with pattern

Tags: html, validation

I'm using HTML5 form validation to validate phone numbers from India.

Phone numbers from India are 10 digits long, and start with 7, 8, or 9.

For example:

1. 7878787878
2. 9898989898
3. 8678678878

These phone numbers are valid, but

1. 1212121212
2. 3434545464
3. 6545432322

are invalid.

Suggest a pattern that can detect valid India phone numbers.

So far, my pattern is `[0-9]{10}`, but it doesn't check if the first digit is 7, 8, or 9.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27000681/1256925) should help you validate phone numbers for all over the world. It also includes validation for other types of input.

Comment: Why not use min="7000000000" and max="9999999999" ?

Comment: starting from 6 mobile numbers are also valid [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How about this? `/(7|8|9)\d{9}/`

It starts by either looking for 7 or 8 or 9, and then followed by 9 digits.

Comment: why /d is used in pattern. what is meaning?

Comment: \d means any digit and the {9} is 9 instances of any digit.

Comment: congo dude its works i big relief. but why you have placed / at staring and ending of pattern.

Comment: the / at the beginning and end of the regular expression denotes the beginning and end of the regular expression.  So, in your code, it's this: 
var myRegEx = /(7|8|9)\d{9}/;

Comment: you may also want to add a terminator to the end of the regular expression otherwise it may accept other characters after the nine digits so you should have `/(7|8|9)\d{9}$/`

Comment: its failed on 789999999999999 . number count more than 10+

Comment: For it to work with more numbers, you'd have to write it like this: /(7|8|9)\d{9,}/
The comma after the 9 means 9 or more.

Answer (score 102):

How about

```
<input type="text" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}">
```

Comment: However, I would recommend adding both the start and end anchors due to browsers being inconsistent with following the HTML5 specification about anchoring - Chrome and Firefox have both only anchored at the start at some point in the past.

Answer (score 13):

Try this code:

```
<input type="text" name="Phone Number" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" 
       title="Phone number with 7-9 and remaing 9 digit with 0-9">
```

This code will inputs only in the following format:

9238726384 (starting with 9 or 8 or 7 and other 9 digit using any number) 
8237373746 
7383673874

*Incorrect format:* 
2937389471(starting not with 9 or 8 or 7) 
32796432796(more than 10 digit) 
921543(less than 10 digit)

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain any information which is not already provided by any of the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

The regex validation for india should make sure that +91 is used, then make sure that 7, 8,9  is used after +91 and finally followed by 9 digits.

`/^+91(7\d|8\d|9\d)\d{9}$/`

### Your original regex doesn't require a "+" at the front though.

`Get the more information from below link` 
[w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: I think a better solution for this is `/^[+]91(9|8|7)\d{9}$/` which is more appropriate for ECMA6. We don't really need the \d while checking for the first digit.

Answer (score 6):

This code will accept all country code with + sign

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{7}[-][0-9]{1}"/>
```

Some countries allow a single "0" character instead of "+" and others a double "0" character instead of the "+". Neither are standard.

Comment: sorry but i can't see + sign in the pattern

Answer (score 6):

Improving [@JamesPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611675/8444348)'s answer:

Since now in India, a new series of phone numbers started with `6`. Use this

```
<input type="text" pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}">
```

To show a custom error message, use the `title` attribute.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" title="Please enter valid phone number">
```

That's all folks.

Comment: How can I show the title message in mat-error ? Somehow title is not working this way.

Comment: @OptimistRohit I think this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884655/display-custom-validator-error-with-mat-error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### ^[789]\d{9,9}$

- Minimum digits 10
- Maximum digits 10
- number starts with 7,8,9