# how to validate the mobile number in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to validate my mobile no field in html page by using jquery any idea

**Html**

```
<input type="text"  required="true" validType="" name="Ph" id="ph" value=""  />
```

what i hv to put in validType for this

e.g when we hv to validate the email we just put email in the validType

Comment: Did you implemented any of jquery code to validate?

Comment: do you have any format or simple 1-10 you want to accept?

Comment: i want to accept 1-10 but if possible it must start from 9,8 or 7

Comment: hi ashwani please tell me what all are the requirements for your mobile number validations?

Comment: i hv explained it in above comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Jquery onchange function

```
$("#ph").change(function() {
        var a = $("#ph").val();
        var filter = /^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;

        if (filter.test(a)) {
            alert("valid");
        }
        else {
            alert("not valid");
        }
    });
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GxuA7/35 click on this link and see the vaildation

Comment: like which i give in validType tag

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html-5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern

Comment: how do i get that jquery used in the link you used

Comment: But there will be browser issue when you use pattern so try to validate manually..let me know your suggestions

Comment: click on the link which I provided it will give result.tell me if you have a problem

Comment: its working by pattern but the error shown by jquery is regarding pattern...i want it to show the phone no error...is their any option to do it

Comment: When using pattern= it will display whatever you put in the title attrib,so keep title="your error message" tell me if it worked?

Comment: You are welcome please accept the answser it will be useful if someone looking the validation in jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<input type="tel" pattern="[\+]\d{2}[(]\d{2}[)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}" />`

Comment: And more like pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}'

Comment: @Dipaks Updated with yours :)

Comment: When using pattern= it will display whatever you put in the title attrib,so keep title="your error message" tell me if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code :

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="txt"/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#submit",function(e){
        var mobile = $("#phone").val();
        var mob_length = mobile.length;
        var first = mobile.substring(0,1);

        if(mob_length != 10)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if((first == 9 || first == 8 || first == 7))
        {
            alert("Working");
        }
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```