# jQuery Validation making new rules

Tags: jquery, validation

so I have a sign up form and I want to validate it with the jQuery Validation. I'm a beginnner and I'm not really sure how it works..
Lets say I have an input of a phone number:

```
<label class="labelinput" for="phonenum">Phone Number: </label>
<input type="text" id="cell" name="cell" class="forminput" /><br />
```

And I want to validate with jQuery that the first digit is zero and that it's length is 10 digits. How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to use jquery, because you can do that with plain html.

Comment: if you use HTML5, then use pattern for it. for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html-5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern

Comment: html is good to.. how can I do it with html?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
$(function(){
var phonenum = $('#cell').val();

if(!isNaN(parseFloat(phonenum )) && isFinite(phonenum ) && phonenum.length==10 && phonenum.charAt(0)=='0' ){
   alert('Correct Input');

}
else{
  alert('Wrong Input');
}

});
```

**NOTE:**

```
!isNaN(parseFloat(phonenum )) && isFinite(phonenum )
```

The above condition checks that the entered charcters are `numeric characters`.

This was just a simple solution.

If you want to use `Regex` you might want to take a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query like

```
if($('#cell').val().length!=10 && $('#cell').val().charAt(0)!='0')
{
  alert('Wrong number input');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression:

```
if (!/^[0]\d{9}$/.test($('#cell').val())) {
    // wrong phone number
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo60d0ju/)

Comment: Thanks but how can I use that in jQuery validation? How do I use that as one of the rules?