# How to add validation of mobile no dyanamically in js

Tags: javascript, html

How to add validation of mobile no.
Html code:`<input type="text" id="mob" name="mob[]" placeholder="Enter mobile no" required>`

js code

```
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("mobile"));
var input_m = document.createElement("input");
input_m.type = "text";
input_m.id= id+'_mobile';
input_m.name= "mob[]";
container.appendChild(input_m);
```

Comment: what do you want in your validation

Comment: For Indian numbers: `/[7-9][0-9]{9}/`. Note this is a basic validation regex. This will not cover cases like `9999999999`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 phone number validation with pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this through regex:

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  {  
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)) {  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Note, its better to use `regex.test`