# Restricting input text to only numbers and with minimum length to 10 for phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to restrict my text box to only numbers with minimum length to 10 and another version like accept + at the start and after two & three & numbers - should come..like +91-123-456-7890

Here is my code

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) 
this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">
```

Comment: Whats the +number for if you're restricting it to 2 numbers, country codes have 1 to 3 numbers(e.g 1 for US and Canada, or 353 for ROI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using library-less javascript (rather than jQuery):

```js
var numberInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('tel');
var paragraph = document.querySelector('form p');

function checkInput(i) {
    var input = numberInputs[i];
    var inputLength = input.value.length;
    var inputMax = parseInt(numberInputs[i].getAttribute('maxlength'));
    
    if ((inputLength > 0) && (!input.value[(inputLength - 1)].match(/\d/))) {

    input.value = input.value.substring(0, (inputLength - 1));
    inputLength = input.value.length;
    input.style.borderColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    paragraph.textContent = 'Please write only numbers';
    paragraph.style.color = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';

    }

    else {
        input.removeAttribute('style');
        paragraph.textContent = '';
    }

    if (inputLength === inputMax) {
    
        if (i < (numberInputs.length - 1)) {
            numberInputs[(i+1)].focus();    
        }

        else {
            paragraph.textContent = 'Your number is: +' + numberInputs[0].value;
    
            for (var j = 1; j < numberInputs.length; j++) {
                paragraph.textContent += '-' + numberInputs[j].value;
            }

            paragraph.style.color = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';   
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < numberInputs.length; i++) {
    numberInputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(){checkInput(i);}, false);
}
```

```html
<form>
+
<input class="tel" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" />
-
<input class="tel" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
-
<input class="tel" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
-
<input class="tel" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
<p></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" title="Enter 10 digits">
```

Comment: its not working @bhupesh, from my code i'm able to restrict user entering alphabets but need to make it minimum length to 10 ofcourse i made the max length to 10

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern

Comment: Good use of the `pattern` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<input type=“number” oninput=“slice(0,10)”>
```