# Keypress validation which should not allow alphabet only but all other key should work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Validation: I need only number space and plus symbol in a textbox

```
$('#value').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if ($('#value').val().length == 0) {
        if (e.which == 32) { //space bar
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
        if (!valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122 || e.which == 32 || e.which == 95 || e.which == 8);
        if (!valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you `console.log(charCode);` before the `if` what is logged for space?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: In this above code i just want the space-bar key to work..number and plus symbol key is working but space- bar key is not working

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are approaching this the wrong way. The term you are looking for is "validation", and there are many good ways to go about it. I recommend you look into [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375929/validate-phone-number-using-javascript). Regular expressions are the way to go, though you could also do this with pure HTML5 without needing to get Javascript involved. Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611599/html5-phone-number-validation-with-pattern) and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/client-side-form-validation-html5/).

Comment: I dont want specific format, But I need a textbox which will not allow alphabet but rest all key should work